# Odoo 9 edit button on website not visible

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I can't edit website in odoo 9 with admin account. Edit button in left corner in not visible, how fix problem.

Any solution for this problem.

Comment: Have you checked the if the Admin user is included in the Manage Website and qWeb view group? I would expect the Admin to be a part of this group however you might as well check.

Comment: @phillipstack  admin is member of group Website / Editor and Designer  and Website / Editor other group with contains "WebSite" don't exist.

Comment: Check out this how to on Odoo Theme Support "https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/themes.html" I think the theme support packages need to be installed like website_less.